# jquery fixed position block, swtich to static certaint point

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I got a block of content:

```
<div id="content_holder">
  <div id="fixed_content"></div>
  <div id="bottom_content"></div>
</div>
```

I want to achieve this - when i scroll down with my mouse, the `fixed_content` block would turn fixed position and will stick on top of page, until i scroll down to `bottom_content`.

So far i got this:

```
var top_positio_saver = $('#fixed_content').offset().top;
$(document).on('scroll', function() {
  if ($('#fixed_content').offset().top < $(document).scrollTop()) {
    $('#fixed_content').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('#fixed_content').css('top', 0);
  }
  if ($(document).scrollTop() < top_positio_saver) {
    $('#fixed_content').css('position', 'static');
    $('#fixed_content').css('top', 0);
    $('#fixed_content').css('margin-top', 0);
  }
});
```

With this code, the `fixed_content` block is fixed once i scroll down enough, and turns back to static once i scroll up enough. The problem here is that if i scroll down too much, this block goes on top of `bottom_content` block, instead i want it to stop near the bottom_content block.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the distance between the bottom block's `offset.top()` and the current document's `scrollTop()`.

The following code is supposed to work. Notice you can set multiple settings with the same [.css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) call. Also notice the second `if` condition was redundant and could be replaced with an `else` condition.

The logic is that if the `scrollTop` has reached 550px, but the bottom content starts from 500px, the `#fixed_content` element will start from `top: -50px`. That way we're preventing the overflowing.

```
var top_positio_saver = $('#fixed_content').offset().top;
$(document).on('scroll', function() {

  if (top_positio_saver <= $(document).scrollTop()) {
    var distance = $('#bottom_content').offset().top - $(document).scrollTop();
    var newTop = Math.min(0, distance);

    $('#fixed_content').css({
                                'position': 'fixed',
                                'top': newTop
                            });
  }
  else {
    $('#fixed_content').css({
                                'position': 'static',
                                'top': 0,
                                'margin-top': 0
                            });
  }
});
```